# Navigation Controller Display Prompt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

How can I make my `UINavigationController` display a prompt when a button is pressed? I have already set my text by `[[[self navigationController]navigationItem]setPrompt:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Prompt is working!"]];`

EDIT:
To clarify, I have a button calling an `IBAction`that sets the prompt as follows but I need to find a way to display the prompt as soon as that button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)test:(id)sender
{
    [[[self navigationController]navigationItem]setPrompt:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Prompt works!"]];
    //I want it to display right after I set it, so I'm missing something and can't figure it out through the documentation
}
```

I have already tried `[[[self navigationController]navigationBar]pushNavigationItem:nav animated:YES];` but that throws an error stating `Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.`

Comment: You should post more code. What's the problem, the button?

Comment: When is the prompt displayed?

Comment: I want it to be displayed when the user presses the button.

Comment: Yes, but when is the prompt displayed with this code? Is it ever displayed or is it delayed?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I misunderstood you. It is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should set the prompt text like this:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"This is the title";
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! What was wrong with the way I was doing it?

Comment: UINavigationController gets all navigation bar items information (buttons, title view, prompt etc.) from the current top view controller it displays. So you need to set those on the view controller itself, not on the navigation controller.